# using tesseract on MTG cards

Tags: image-processing, ocr, python-tesseract

my first hurdle so far is that running tesseract vanilla on images of MTG cards doesn't recognize the card title (honestly that's all I need because I can use that text to pull the rest of the card info from a database) I think the issue might be having to need to train tesseract to recognize the font use in mtg cards but im wondering if it might be an issue with tesseract not looking or not detecting text in a section of the image (specifically the title.)

Edit: including an image of a MTG card for reference.http://gatherer.wizards.com/Handlers/Image.ashx?multiverseid=175263&type=card

Comment: Post an image sample

Comment: What's an MTG card? How do they look? What quality images of them do you have? What OS do you use?

Comment: here is a sample of an image of a MTG card.http://gatherer.wizards.com/Handlers/Image.ashx?multiverseid=175263&type=card

i've used various different resolutions from around 600px  up to 1080px. this is running off of a raspberry pi2, the Raspbian OS

Comment: Is that an example of a particular image you're running Tesseract on, or just a sample of an M:tG card? A sample of the former is more important than the latter....

Comment: it is one of the one of the ones i used along with 
http://gatherer.wizards.com/Handlers/Image.ashx?multiverseid=236504&type=card
||
http://demogorgon.com/temp/MTG-Demogorgon-Card.jpg
||
http://img13.deviantart.net/b10e/i/2013/047/c/e/avacyn__mtg_card_by_entroz-d5v7in5.png
||
http://orig13.deviantart.net/2129/f/2010/307/b/7/tinker_alternate_art_mtg_card_by_dodgeimagery-d322pze.jpg
||
http://media.wizards.com/images/magic/daily/ftl/uytdsce5vrsdfgs.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Ok so, after asking on reddit programming forums I think I found an answer that I am going to pursue:

> The training feature of tesseract is indeed for improving rates for unusual fonts, but that's probably not the reason you have low success.
>   The environment the text is in is not well controlled - the card background can be a texture in one of five colours plus artifacts and lands. Tesseract greyscales the image before processing, so the contrast between the text and background is not sufficient.
>   You could put your cards through a preprocessor which mutes coloured areas to white and enhances monotones. That should increase the contrast so tesseract can make out the characters.

If anyone still following thsi believes that above path to be the wrong one to start down, please say so.

Answer (score 0):

## TLDR

I believe you're on the right track, doing preprocessing.

But you will need doing both preprocessing AND training Tesseract.

## Preprocessing

Basically, you want to get the title text, and only the title text, for Tesseract to read. I suggest you follow the steps below:

1. Identify the borders of the card.
2. Cut out the title area for further processing.
3. Convert the image to black'n'white.
4. Use contours to identify the exact text area, and crop it out.
5. Send the image you got to Tesseract.

How to create a basic preprocessing is shown in the YouTube video [Automatic MTG card sorting: Part 2 - Automatic perspective correction with OpenCV](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NqOnnQw9rZk) Also have a look at the third part in that serie.

With this said, there is a number of problems you will encounter. How to handle split cards? Will your algorithm manage white borders? What if the card is rotated or upside-down? just to name a few.

## Need for Training

But even if you manage to create a perfect preprocessing algorithm you will still have to train Tesseract. This is due to the special text font used on the cards (which happens to be different fonts depending on the age of the card!).

Consider the card "Kinjalli's Caller".

http://gatherer.wizards.com/Handlers/Image.ashx?multiverseid=435169&type=card

Note how similar the "j" is to the "i". An untrained Tesseract tend to mix them up.

## Conclusion

All this considered, my answer to you is that **you need to do both preprocessing of the card image AND to train Tesseract**.

If you're still interested I would like to suggest that you have a look at this MTG-card reading project on GitHub. That way you don't have to reinvent the wheel.

https://github.com/klanderfri/ReadMagicCard